# Using environment variable (or Similar) in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, environment-variables

Currently, I have a site that does ajax calls to a specific server and gets data from it.

So, I have put the site address in every ajax call.

Is there a way to declare it outside the file into another file and be called from there?

(Ex. Like in Python, we can same environment variables and call them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a config object in the global scope:

```js
const config = {
  MY_VAR: "my value"
}

;(function() {
  console.log(config.MY_VAR)
})();
```